# spawn: How to pass arguments to spawn within an expect script?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, parameter-passing, expect

I just have a bigger *bash-script* where I stumbled into a problem, to use *ssh* to connect to another computer. That one is visited first time (always, really ;) ) and therefore asks *The authenticity of host '[192.168.120.170]:9022 ([192.168.120.170]:9022)' can't be established.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?*

So I tried to answer this question using an **additional** expect/spawn script.

So I have two files:
**deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
... Some functions and more
# call expect script to get a first time onto the target
/usr/bin/expect -d -f ./deployImage_helper.exp -- -p 9022 root@192.168.120.170
```

**deploy_helper.exp**

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect  -f
set args [lrange $argv 1 end]
spawn ssh {*}$args
expect "The authenticity of host'[192.168.120.170]([192.168.120.170]:9022)' can't be established."
send "yes"
```

If I run **deploy.sh** I get the error message: **invalid command name "192.168.120.170"**

Somehow I don't get spawn running *ssh*.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Changed **deploy.sh** line 4

Comment: `expect -d -f deploy_helper.exp -- 192.168.120.170 -p 9022` and see what's wrong.

Comment: I added debug output and updated the EDIT above. The output is:   **argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = -f  argv[3] = ./deployImage_helper.exp  argv[4] = --  argv[5] = -p  argv[6] = 9022  argv[7] = root@192.168.120.170  
set argc 3
set argv0 "./deployImage_helper.exp"
set argv "-p 9022 root@192.168.120.170"
executing commands from command file ./deployImage_helper.exp
spawn ssh -p 9022 root@192.168.120.170
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {6570}**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set args [lrange $argv 1 end]
spawn ssh {*}$args
expect -re {The authenticity of .* can't be established.} {
    send "yes"
}

interact
```

Inside `""` variables and square brakets `[]` (evaluate command inside brackets and place result instead), will be expanded and evaluated. You need quote square brackets `\[` or use `{}` instead of `""`.
BTW, you can supress asking this question (only warning showing) by openssh options:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 9022 root@192.168.120.170
```

Comment: Thanks a lot komar